# Should I use JavaFx properties?

Tags: java, design, object-oriented, mvc, javafx

I'm usually very careful to keep my Model, View, and Controller code separate. The thing is JavaFx properties are so convenient to bind them all together. The issue is that it makes my entire code design dependent on JavaFx, which I feel I should not being doing. I should be able to change the view without changing too much of the model and controller.

So should I ignore the convenience of JavaFx properties, or should I embrace them and the fact that it reduces my codes flexibility.

Comment: Good question. And quite possibly one of the reasons this graph looks the way it does, [HTML5 vs JavaFX in the headlines](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=html5,javafx) Perhaps if more consideration had gone into how to implement JavaFX it would have done better.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use JavaFX properties without rest of JavaFX. If thats true, your model would depend on one more library. And if you only privide hooks for gui, but without knowing the gui (to be sure, develop it separately), it would be OK.

Something other is depending on actual properties of your gui objects. That forces you to change model when you do trivial changes to gui and vice versa.